# Accessing system performance data directly from the linux kernel

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel

I need to write an application that gets performance statistics on a Linux machine. Unfortunately the environment is extremely memory constrained and so using the standard command line tools isn't really an option as I would need to poll them pretty frequently.

Ideally what I would like to be able to do would be to get the performance data directly from the kernel itself, using the same buffers and data that it uses to try and reduce the RAM requirements for my application as much as possible. Tying my app to the Linux kernel so closely isn't really a problem we have only ever used Linux in production and I can't see that ever changing really.

I've spent the last day or two looking through the kernel source but I have to admit to being somewhat lost. Can anyone point me to the right place for getting access to CPU performance information / I/O performance information / networking performance information and bandwidth usage information please?

Comment: If a command-line tool can access that information, then you can access it too without having to be in the kernel. You can probably read the source of your favorite command-line tool to find out how it works. Don't try to "live in the kernel" unless there's a **very** good reason.

Comment: Take a look at [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), it might be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are several files under /proc, such as /proc/stat, /proc/diskstats, /proc/net/*.

For CPU performance information, using /proc/stat, the file format is defined in the file ./fs/proc/stat.c in Linux Kernel source code tree.

For disk access information, using /proc/diskstats, the file format is defined in the file ./block/genhd.c in Linux Kernel source code tree, the function is diskstats_show().

For network related statistics, one can refer to files under /proc/net/. But I don't know how to calculate the bandwidth usage based on file under directory /proc/net.

Comment: All of the files under `/proc` should be read, inside a user-land application. Most of them (e.g. `/proc/$pid/stat` or `/proc/$pid/maps` should be read sequentially, like pipes or soqkets).